# Add python syntax highlighting to jython-tagged questions by default

Tags: feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

I would suggest to add python syntax highlighting to questions tagged [jython](/questions/tagged/jython) by default. Of course, you can add `<!-- language: lang-py -->` to those questions and answers [manually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work), but not everybody knows that. And I think re-tagging those questions with [python](/questions/tagged/python) would not be desired.

Comment: You're probably right, but I have a few questions before I pull the trigger on this. I see the [jython] tag coupled with [python] and [java] hundreds of times each. Does Jython code ever resemble Java? In other words, would anyone ever be adding `<!-- language: lang-java -->` to make their code highlight correctly? Also, do you think the [python] and [java] tags should be removed from a lot of [jython] questions once the default highlighting is set?

Comment: Well, I understand your concerns. I'm not very involved in the tag hierarchy debate, and my first thought was that a post tagged [jython] should not at the same time be tagged [python], but after reading and thinking about it, maybe the best way is that every [jython] post gets a [python] tag as well, with Jython questions being a subset of Python questions... How does syntax highlighting work in the presence of several applicable tags, BTW?

Comment: I think it just picks the most popular language tag, which can be a problem. I do think that making Python syntax highlighting the default is the right thing to do here, I just want to make sure it's not going to create other problems that I don't even know about.